# Touchscreen : apply calibration when plugged

Tags: xorg, touchscreen, xinput

I have a NUC unit to made a kiosk application in a store which runs on Ubuntu.

To make calibration permanent, I made a startup application with xinput commands. Everything IS working fine.

But, NUC unit make a reboot every night and, when doing so, touchscreen is powered off.
When powering on, calibration is not applied, because when xinput startup command launch, it didn't fond any touchscreen.

How Can I made it permanent, whenever if touchscreen is off or unplugged? Can I detect it and launch command after?

Thanks !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.